# "Discouraged to" vs. "Recommended to not"

Tags: writing-style, tech-writing

> - In the past, pregnant women have been recommended to not exercise because of presumed risks of preterm birth.
> - In the past, pregnant women have been discouraged to exercise because of presumed risks of preterm birth.

Which construction is better in technical writing: "discouraged to" or "recommended to not"?

The former one seems to be much more common, but the latter one looks more transparent to me. *(English is not my primary language and so my opinion regarding transparency doesn't have any real value.)* And since, in technical writing, clarity is the paramount, the latter version could be much better.

Still, I'm not sure whichever version to choose.

- `"discouraged to"`: https://ludwig.guru/s/%22discouraged+to%22 - 196 exact results, it seems most of them are from The New York Times, The New Yorker, The Guardian; that is, from general-purpose press.
- `"recommended to not"`: https://ludwig.guru/s/%22recommended+to+not%22 - only 19 exact results, it seems that all of them are from scientific journals.

Since this question is tagged as "writing-style", I hope it won't be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: I would say "discouraged *from*...exercising."

Comment: I agree with WeatherVane that "discouraged from exercising" is much more natural.  In fact, "Discouraged to not exercise" is effectively a double-negative, meaning that when someone said "maybe I should stop exercising" they were told that they should not stop. (It's not a double-negative in the true sense, like "I didn't see no sign", but it is a word with a 'negative sense' combined with a negative.)

Comment: @Hellion "Discouraged to not exercise" was a typo. I still in process of reading your comment. Sorry!

Comment: I would go for "In the past, pregnant women were (used to be) advised not go....."

Comment: ...but I would not use the word 'discouraged' in a technical document, or a phrase that suggests some people might be stupid. I think 'advised' might be better, but such a document should, as you say, be clear, factual and not patronising. Some of the worst technical writing has an air of superiority over lesser mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In academic writing, there is no reason not to report, if relevant, that women were discouraged from exercising when pregnant. Girls have been discouraged from studying science, for example.

Note that “to discourage someone from doing something” is an active use of discouraged; it takes an object. He discouraged her. He discouraged exercise.

On the other hand, “I was discouraged to learn that there were few jobs for women in that field” is using the verb as stative. This seems to be what most of your examples do. The verb is intransitive in this kind of use.

Comment: The question specifically asks for **comparison**: is it better to use *discouraged* **or** *recommmended to not*?